# function navigate() { document.getElementById

Tags: javascript, url, salesforce

I am having an issue trying to figure out how to add custom code to a URL that when clicked, it reloads an iframe on the page. I only have access to the URL.

iframe ID = gfgFrame

`function navigate() { document.getElementById("gfgFrame").src = "/ClientCommunity/s/all-products?fileInfo=abcXyz";}`

URL: javascript:navigate()

How can I add the above directly to the URL instead of using the javascript:navigate() ?

Comment: so call `document.getElementById("gfgFrame").src="/ClientCommunity/s/all-products?fileInfo=abcXyz";` in the href?

Comment: @epascarello - Already tried that. I just appends the code to the end of the URL and comes up 'invalid page'

Comment: with the `javascript:` label? `href="javascript:document.getElementById('gfgFrame')....."`

Comment: when I do that, it just returns a blank page with /ClientCommunity/s/all-products?fileInfo=abcXyz message on the top left of the screen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code line works:

```
javascript:(() => {document.getElementById("gfgFrame").src="/ClientCommunity/s/product-results?fileInfo=xyz";})();
```

Answer (score 0):

If your iframe has a `name` attribute you can just make an anchor with `target="theIframesName"`

```
<a href="/ClientCommunity/s/all-products?fileInfo=abcXyz" target="gfgFrameName">click</a>
```

Comment: Thanks James. I only have access to the URL and I cannot add the target tag.